# Multi-threading does not work correctly using std::thread (C++ 11)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I coded a small c++ program to try to understand how multi-threading works using `std::thread`. Here's the step of my program execution :

1. Initialization of a 5x5 matrix of integers with a unique value '42' contained in the class 'Toto' (initialized in the main).
2. I print the initialized 5x5 matrix.
3. Declaration of `std::vector` of 5 threads.
4. I attach all threads respectively with their task (`threadTask` method). Each thread will manipulate a `std::vector<int>` instance.
5. I join all threads.
6. I print the new state of my 5x5 matrix.

Here's the output :

```
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42

42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
```

It should be :

```
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42

0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
```

Here's the code sample :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class       Toto
{
public:
    /*
    ** Initialize a 5x5 matrix with the 42 value.
    */
    void    initData(void)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            std::vector<int> vec;

            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                vec.push_back(42);
            }
            this->m_data.push_back(vec);
        }
    }

    /*
    ** Display the whole matrix.
    */
    void    printData(void) const
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                printf("%d ", this->m_data[y][x]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*
    ** Function attached to the thread (thread task).
    ** Replace the original '42' value by the another one.
    */
    void    threadTask(std::vector<int> &list, int value)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            list[x] = value;
        }
    }

    /*
    ** Return a sub vector reference according to the range.
    */

    std::vector<int>    &getDataByRange(int range)
    {
        return (this->m_data[range]);
    }

    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > m_data;
};

int         main(void)
{
    Toto    toto;

    toto.initData();

    toto.printData(); //Display the original 5x5 matrix (first display).

    std::vector<std::thread> threadList(5); //Initialization of vector of 5 threads.

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  //Threads initializationss

        std::vector<int> &vec = toto.getDataByRange(i); //Get each sub-vectors reference.
        threadList.at(i) = std::thread(&Toto::threadTask, toto, vec, i); //Each thread will be attached to a specific vector.
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        threadList.at(j).join();
    }

    toto.printData(); //Second display.
    getchar();

    return (0);
}
```

However, in the method `threadTask`, if I print the variable `list[x]`, the output is correct. I think I can't print the correct data in the main because the printData() call is in the main thread and the display in the `threadTask` function is correct because the method is executed in its own thread (not the main one). It's strange, it means that all threads created in a parent processes can't modified the data in this parent processes ? I think I forget something in my code. I'm really lost. Does anyone can help me, please ?
Thank a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to learn about C++ value and reference semantics. `std::vector<int> vec = toto.getData()[i];` makes a copy of the vector so the original never gets changed. That copy then gets copied into the thread object as well, and again, never affects the original.

Comment: I updated my question using getDataByRange new function that returns a reference to a specific sub-vector according to a range. So I does not return a copy but a reference. The output is the same than after my modification.

Comment: The problem wasn't with the getData function, it was with the std::vector<int> vec = ... part. This calls vecs copy constructor and vec will be a different object than what is returned by getData.

As a side note. Consider initializing your vector in the classes constructor using the vectors constructors.

Toto() : m_data(5, std::vector<int>(5, 42) ) {
}

is a much cleaner implementation in my opinion.

Comment: The subject has been updated. I use getDataByRange new method which returns a reference a vector according to its range (std::vector<int> &vec = toto.getDataByRange(i)).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that many of the choices you've made in writing this are making your job substantially more difficult than necessary. In particular, your `toto` class seems (to me) to make client code more complex rather than simpler, and fails to encapsulate the data it manipulates. I think if I were going to do this, I'd write code more along these general lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::vector<int> const &d) {
    for (auto const &v : d)
        os << v << "\t";
    return os;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::vector <std::vector<int>> const &d) {
    for (auto const &v : d)
        os << v << "\n";
    return os;
}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> d(5, std::vector<int>(5, 42));

    std::cout << d;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        threads.emplace_back([i, &d]() {std::fill(d[i].begin(), d[i].end(), i); });

    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread &t){t.join(); });

    std::cout << "\n" << d;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem. All comes from the line :

```
threadList.at(i) = std::thread(&Toto::threadTask, toto, **vec**, i);
```

which must be :

```
threadList.at(i) = std::thread(&Toto::threadTask, toto, **&vec**, i);
```

and my function 'threadTask' have to takes a pointer (not a reference) in first parameter.

```
void    threadTask(std::vector<int> *list, int value)
    {
        printf("b=%p\n", list);
        getchar();
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            (*list)[x] = value;
        }
    }
```

I hope this example will help somebody.

Comment: Alternatively, you may use a reference like the first attempt.  However you would call std::thread with std::ref as a parameter like so: `std::thread(&Toto::threadTask, toto, std::ref(vec), i);`